java streams: collect appending strings into existing StringBuilder
Here my related code:
  public String build() {
    StringBuilder s3Key = new StringBuilder();

    if (bucketName == null || fileName == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Bucket name and file name are required");
    }

    s3Key.append(bucketName);

    String prefix = paths.stream().filter(Predicate.not(Strings::isNullOrEmpty)).collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
    s3Key.append(prefix);

    s3Key.append(fileName);

    return s3Key.toString();
  }

Is there any way to collect streamed string into existent s3Key StringBuilder?

You can define your own collector with Collector.of. The code is going to be quite a bit less readable than what you already have.

Easier than using a Stream:  paths.removeIf(s -> s == null || s.isBlank()); return String.join("/", paths);

If you don't mind use of JDK built-in Predicate and validation as  NullPointerException rather than IllegalStateException you can re-write as a one-liner:
return Objects.requireNonNull(bucketName, "Bucket name is required")
     + paths.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                     .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
                     .collect(Collectors.joining("/"))
     + Objects.requireNonNull(fileName,   "File name is required");

Note: the above preserves behaviour of your stated code, which does not insert "/" between the bucketName and fileName parts.
EDIT
Note Holger's suggestion below on using Collectors.joining("/", prefix, suffix), and as this call performs not null checks on prefix and suffix, the one-line definition can be shortened to:
return paths.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("/", bucketName, fileName));


You could also use paths.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull) .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)) .collect(Collectors.joining("/", Objects.requireNonNull(bucketName, "Bucket name is required"), Objects.requireNonNull(fileName,   "File name is required")));

@Holger That's a good idea, and as it looks like Collectors.joining uses Objects.requireNonNull it is even short as paths.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)).collect(Collectors.joining("/", bucketName, fileName))

Try it like this.
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This is a test");

String[] str = {" to", " append", " more", " information."};
Arrays.stream(str).reduce(sb, (a,b)->a.append(b), (a,b)->a);

System.out.println(sb);

prints
This is a test to append more information.

You could also do the following:
sb.append(Arrays.stream(str).collect(Collectors.joining()));        


You don't even need to use a string builder at all. Just join the parts with a forward-slash, after prepending the bucket name, and appending the filename.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class S3Resource {
    private String bucketName;
    private String fileName;
    private List<String> paths;

    public String build() {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(bucketName) || !StringUtils.hasText(fileName)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bucket name and file name are required");
        }

        // Collect all valid paths into a single list
        List<String> validPaths = paths.stream()
                .filter(StringUtils::hasText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        validPaths.addFirst(bucketName);
        validPaths.addLast(fileName);

        return String.join("/", validPaths);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S3Resource resource = new S3Resource();
        resource.setBucketName("my-bucket");
        resource.setFileName("my-file.txt");
        resource.setPaths(List.of("path1", "path2"));

        System.out.println(resource.build()); // my-bucket/path1/path2/my-file.txt
    }

    static class StringUtils {
        public static boolean hasText(String s) {
            return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
        }
    }
}

